# Moq: Test parameters sent with sequence of method calls

Tags: c#, moq

I'm new to C# Moq (used Rhino Mochs in the past) and needing to test a sequence of calls to the same method.  I found this cool solution that tests a sequence of return values:

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/29/moq-sequences.aspx/

```
public static class MoqExtensions
{
  public static void ReturnsInOrder<T, TResult>(this ISetup<T, TResult> setup, 
    params TResult[] results) where T : class  {
    setup.Returns(new Queue<TResult>(results).Dequeue);
  }
}
```

What I need to do is to test the *values sent* as a parameter to the method (rather than the values it returns) in a sequence of calls to the same method.

Rough outline ...

```
 var expression = new MyExpressionThing();

 processor.Setup(x => x.Execute(expected1)).Verifiable();
 processor.Setup(x => x.Execute(expected2)).Verifiable();
 processor.Setup(x => x.Execute(expected3)).Verifiable();

 expression.ExecuteWith(processor.Object);
 processor.Verify();
```

Here's what I've attempted but I'm getting the exception:

"System.ArgumentException : Invalid callback. Setup on method with parameters (String,Object[]) cannot invoke callback with parameters (String)."

```
 // Arrange
 var processor = new Mock<IMigrationProcessor>();
 IList<string> calls = new List<string>();
 processor.Setup(p => p.Execute(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Callback<string>(s => calls.Add(s));

// Act
var expr = new ExecuteScriptsInDirectoryExpression { SqlScriptDirectory = @"SQL2\1_Pre" };
expr.ExecuteWith(processor.Object);

// Assert
calls.ToArray().ShouldBe(new[]
   { "DELETE FROM PRE1A", "DELETE FROM PRE1B", "INSERT INTO PRE2\r\nLINE2" });
```

Looks like I'm using boilerplate code from the Moq "Getting Started" examples:

This link discusses this exception and links to the Moq code that fires it.

http://dailydevscoveries.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/invalid-callback-setup-on-method-with.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a callback to capture the parameter each time the mock is called, and then assert the result:

```
var parameters = new List<ParameterType>();
processor.Setup(x => x.Execute(It.IsAny<ParameterType>()))
    .Callback<ParameterType>(param => parameters.Add(param));

CallCodeUnderTest(processor.Object);

Assert.That(parameters, Is.EqualTo(new[] { expected1, expected2, expected3 }));
```

**Update:** Based on the error message you quoted, it looks like the method you're mocking takes a second parameter that's a `params object[]`. You don't need to specify that parameter when you call the method (which is why you don't need it in the `Setup` lambda), but you do need to specify it in the generic type parameters to `.Callback`. Change your `Callback` line to:

```
    .Callback<string, object[]>((s, o) => calls.Add(s));
```

Comment: Yeah. Tried that. I'm getting

"System.ArgumentException : Invalid callback. Setup on method with parameters (String,Object[]) cannot invoke callback with parameters (String)."

Comment: See edit -- you may need to call `.Callback<T>` and specify the type parameters, instead of relying on type inference.

Comment: Yep. I'm doing that.  See updates above that shows my exact code.

Comment: Ahhh ... My bad I failed to give you the whole exception detail. 

"System.ArgumentException : Invalid callback. Setup on method with parameters (String,Object[]) cannot invoke callback with parameters (String).
   at Moq.MethodCall.ThrowParameterMismatch(ParameterInfo[] expected, ParameterInfo[] actual)
   at Moq.MethodCall.SetCallbackWithArguments(Delegate callback)
   at Moq.MethodCall.Callback(Action`1 callback)"

So I suspect that my code being tested is throwing an exception :)>

Comment: Nope. That's not it.  Maybe I'm running an old version of Moq that does not support this feature. I'm hacking an open source project that may have an old Moq lib.

Comment: Using Moq v4.0.0.0 which is fairly recent.

Comment: The error message is telling you what's wrong -- you're specifying a callback that only takes a `string` parameter, but the method you're mocking takes two parameters, a `string` and an `object[]`. Your callback has to explicitly specify both parameters, even if the second one is optional. See edit.

Comment: YES! Thanks that's it.  

     void Execute(string template, params object[] args);